# Determining meeting attendance rate from awkward CSV file using R tidyverse

Tags: csv, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a CSV file with meeting attendances recorded in this style (see example below):

```
meeting_tbl <- tribble(

  ~ dates, ~ attendees,

  "14/12/2023", "John Smith / John Brown / Jim Green / Jim Green / Larry Smith / Mary Green / Eddie Jones / Simon Pascal / Blair Jones / Alice Brown",
  "15/11/2023", "John Smith / Michael Thomas / John Brown / Grace Wiley / Sally Rees / Jim Green / Larry Smith / Mary Green / Eddie Jones",
  "18/10/2023", "John Smith / Michael Thomas / John Brown / Grace Wiley / Jim Green / Larry Smith / Mary Green / Eddie Jones / Simon Pascal",
  "12/09/2023", "John Smith / Jim Green / Larry Smith / Larry Smith / Eddie Jones / Simon Pascal / Blair Jones / Jonathan Bing / Fred Smith / Eugene Brown"

  )
```

---

I would like to create a tidy format table from this CSV where I can easily calculate the percentage attendance of individuals to meetings to furnish an annual report. Some of the names are repeated multiple times in the same meeting.

I am an R beginner and am stumped - would appreciate any advice anyone can give. I can't see any similar problems in SO.

Thanks in advance.

Stumped.

Tried using `dplyr::separate_wider_delim()` with `delim = " / "` but ended up with each attendee's name as a column which is not what I think I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_split()` to turn the attendee strings into vectors with an entry for each attendee.
`tidyr::unnest()` turns each vector entry in a separate row and `dplyr::distinct()` removes
duplicated attendee entrys by meeting.

```r
library(tidyverse)

meeting_tbl_long <-
  meeting_tbl |>
  mutate(attendees = str_split(attendees, " / ")) |>
  unnest(attendees) |>
  distinct()

meeting_tbl_long
#> # A tibble: 36 × 2
#>    dates      attendees   
#>    <chr>      <chr>       
#>  1 14/12/2023 John Smith  
#>  2 14/12/2023 John Brown  
#>  3 14/12/2023 Jim Green   
#>  4 14/12/2023 Larry Smith 
#>  5 14/12/2023 Mary Green  
#>  6 14/12/2023 Eddie Jones 
#>  7 14/12/2023 Simon Pascal
#>  8 14/12/2023 Blair Jones 
#>  9 14/12/2023 Alice Brown 
#> 10 15/11/2023 John Smith  
#> # ℹ 26 more rows
```

Calculate attendance percent for each attendee:

```r
meeting_tbl_long |>
  count(attendees) |>
  mutate(percent = n / nrow(meeting_tbl))
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>    attendees          n percent
#>    <chr>          <int>   <dbl>
#>  1 Alice Brown        1    0.25
#>  2 Blair Jones        2    0.5 
#>  3 Eddie Jones        4    1   
#>  4 Eugene Brown       1    0.25
#>  5 Fred Smith         1    0.25
#>  6 Grace Wiley        2    0.5 
#>  7 Jim Green          4    1   
#>  8 John Brown         3    0.75
#>  9 John Smith         4    1   
#> 10 Jonathan Bing      1    0.25
#> 11 Larry Smith        4    1   
#> 12 Mary Green         3    0.75
#> 13 Michael Thomas     2    0.5 
#> 14 Sally Rees         1    0.25
#> 15 Simon Pascal       3    0.75
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that works perfectly!
Apologies for the poor question formatting.